# How can I refresh a webpage without the browser asking confirmation message In IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following code to refresh my webpage.I'm still using GET call. But i don't know what was issue with my code

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

I'm not looking for the browser settings tweak. I'm looking for alternative code to refresh without asking.. [image]

Comment: What IE version are you using?

Comment: My IE version : 11.1358.14393.0 @WashingtonGuedes

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've submitted a form before trying to reload the page.

Just use `location.href = location.href` instead of `location.reload()` and it should work as you expect.

Comment: can you share the site to test on it?

Comment: No @kosmos it is not possible

Comment: As per your instruction used like this:                                              
        function refreshWindow(){
  location.href = location.href;
 }
is that ok, But it's not working

Comment: can you, please, edit your post and add all the code involved?

Answer (score 0):

try this. This will request for a page and not a reload. if you have form then refreshing will resubmit the POST data. You can force a get using this code window.location = window.location.href;

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with anchor/hash-urls (including #) not reloading using the solution from Rex...

So I finally ended up by removing the hash part:

```
window.location = window.location.href.split("#")[0];
```

Comment: It's working good in IE, But loosing some data. Please suggest some other thing.